# How can I configure multi-fields support for undeclared new attribute in Elasticsearch Indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch

Default Elasticsearch adds any new attribute into the index mapping with type text that contains the string value but I need multi fields support(text and keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is correct and it can be used for match and term queries, you can find more info about multi-fields [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html).

For fulltext query you can use this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "dynamic_field001": "search"
    }
  }
}
```

and for term query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "dynamic_field001.keyword": "search" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @sushilprj could you please ask your question more clearly! Based on what I understood you can use Template for your Index to do it.